R: How to fit a linear mixed model with a custom covariance structure for two random intercepts
Suppose I have a dataset with repeated measurements on q clusters. I want to fit an LMM with two random intercepts, on the same cluster, with a non-diagonal covariance structure on the random effects (if it were diagonal I assume the model would be un-identifiable).
That is:
y_{ij} = x_{ij}^T\beta + b_{1j} + b_{2j} + \varepsilon_{ij},
where y_{ij} is the i-th observation in the j-th cluster (j = 1, ..., q; i = 1, ... n_j). Again if b_{1j} and b_{2j} are independent I assume the model is un-identifiable but I want them to be correlated. Let b be the vector of random effects of length 2q, then b distributes Gaussian with mean 0 and a 2q X 2q covariance:
q <- 3
rho <- 0.5
sig2b1 <- 1
sig2b2 <- 1
D <- matrix(c(sig2b1 ,rho, rho, sig2b2),nrow = 2) %x% diag(q)
D

[1,]  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0
[2,]  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0
[3,]  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.5
[4,]  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
[5,]  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
[6,]  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  1.0

(Here q = 3, on the diagonal \sigma^2_{b1} = \sigma^2_{b2} = 1 and we have three variance components to estimate not including the residuals variance \sigma^2_e)
Now the model is a standard LMM in vectorized form:
y = X\beta + Zb + \varepsilon,
Let's get some data:
library(mvtnorm)

b <- t(rmvnorm(n = 1, mean = rep(0, 2 * q), sigma = D))
# can do: plot(b[1:q], b[(q+1):(2*q)]) to see the correlation
z <- rep(letters[1:q], times = c(3,3,2) * 10)
n <- length(z)
Z <- model.matrix(~0 + z)
Z <- cbind(Z, Z) # Notice Z is concatenated to itself, Z is of order n X 2q
x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 1 + 2 * x + Z %*% b + rnorm(n)

Using lme4 with two random intercepts, is surprisingly (sometimes) not bad:
library(lme4)

mod <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|z) + (1|z))

# can do: plot(b[1:q], ranef(mod)$z[,1])
# and: plot(b[(q + 1):(2 * q)], ranef(mod)$z[,2])
# and: VarCorr(mod)

But I want to fit the model with the D covariance structure, where there is some correlation between the random intercepts of each cluster j.
